# Why does my UITapGestureRecognizer does not get called when animating the UIView?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a toast view with a `UIImageView` in it, what I want to do is everytime the user taps the image view, the toast dismisses itself. Naturally I configured a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my image view, but the selector function is not getting called. Here's what I did:

```
class ToastView: UIView {

    private var icon: UIImageView!

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupViews()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  
        icon = UIImageView()
        icon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        icon.image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
        icon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(iconHandler))
        icon.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        addSubview(icon)
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.topAnchor, constant: 55),
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
            icon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            icon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }

    @objc private func iconHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // This function is not called
        print("handle icon")
    }
}
```

After some research, I tried to give the `ToastView` a gesture recognizer instead of the image view. So I did give the tap gesture recognizer when showing the toast in my custom `UIViewController` class like this:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {
    private var isShowingToast: Bool = false
    private lazy var toast: ToastView = {
        let toast = ToastView()
        toast.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toast.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissToast)))
        return toast
    }()

    func showToastWithMessage() {
        if !isShowingToast {
            view.addSubview(toast)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.toast.alpha = 1
                self?.toast.frame.origin.y += 10
                self?.isShowingToast = true
            }, completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
                    self?.toast.alpha = 0
                    self?.toast.frame.origin.y -= 10
                }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.isShowingToast = false
                    self?.toast.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            })
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func dismissToast() {
        // This functions does not get called as well
        print("dismiss")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the dismiss function does not print to the console. Is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: What if you delete the keyword `private` from `dismissToast`? Could you check whether that fixes it? Thx.

Comment: What's this?  icon = UIImageView()  It has no frame?

Comment: @matt i just tried it unfortunately the function still not get called

Comment: Whenever I can't get a gesture recognizes to recognize a tap, I always make sure nothing could possibly be covering up the thing that I should be tapping, and make sure I attached everything correctly in storyboard. This clears up my issue basically every time.

Comment: @Eric33187i tried using debug view hierarchy, there's no view that is covering my toast view, it's very strange

Comment: And you attached the gesture to the appropriate view? Maybe try creating another view on the side and just set a gesture to it and see if it works correctly.

Comment: @Eric33187 I did try add a `UILabel` to my toast view and configure the gesture recognizer to it, it still doesn't work as expected though

Comment: Does the toast view have size? A common problem is a zero size superview.

Comment: Check out this article of mine, it covers the common causes: https://www.biteinteractive.com/sherlock-holmes-and-the-mystery-of-the-untappable-button/

Comment: @matt i updated my question, i use `NSLayoutConstraint` to configure the toast's layout size. Please check my `setupConstraints` function. And thank you I will read your article

Comment: @llehcram While animation, it will not be take any user interaction. that will be the issue. put some delay before start second animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this occurs because of your animation. View is all the time in animation status and block tap gesture. U can try call it with delay instead of adding delay for your animation.

```
func showToastWithMessage() {
    if !isShowingToast {
        view.addSubview(toast)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.toast.alpha = 1
            self?.toast.frame.origin.y += 10
            self?.isShowingToast = true
        }, completion: { _ in
            print("Completion")
        })

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.toast.alpha = 0
                self?.toast.frame.origin.y -= 10
            }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.isShowingToast = false
                self?.toast.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }

    }
}
```

This way view going to animate status after 5 sec not with 5 sec delay.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your controller look like:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

private var isShowingToast: Bool = false
 lazy var toast: ToastView = {
    let toast = ToastView()
    toast.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    toast.backgroundColor = .red
    toast.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
    toast.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissToast)))
    return toast
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Add Toast constraints
    view.addSubview(toast)
    toast.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    toast.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toast.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    toast.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    toast.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}

func showToastWithMessage() {
    if !isShowingToast {
        view.addSubview(toast)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.toast.alpha = 1
            self?.toast.frame.origin.y += 10
            self?.isShowingToast = true
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 5.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.toast.alpha = 0
                self?.toast.frame.origin.y -= 10
            }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.isShowingToast = false
                self?.toast.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        })
    }
}

@objc private func dismissToast() {
    // This functions does not get called as well
    print("dismiss")
 }
}
```

And this is your class:

```
class ToastView: UIView {

private var icon = UIImageView()

init() {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupViews()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setupConstraints()
}

private func setupViews() {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    layer.cornerRadius = 8
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    icon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    icon.image = UIImage(named: "profilo")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) //put your image here
    icon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    icon.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    icon.layer.masksToBounds = true //set image masked round corner
    icon.clipsToBounds = true
    icon.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill //set image content mode
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(iconHandler))
    icon.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

private func setupConstraints() {
    // Setup the constraints for the subviews
    addSubview(icon)
    icon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    icon.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

@objc private func iconHandler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // This function is not called
    print("handle icon")
 }
}
```

this is the result:

[image]